# Convert first element of list A to list of first two elements of list A

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In the following code I have a simple list of integers. I want the first element of the list to be the list of the two first elements of the list.

```
import numpy as np

distances=[]
for i in range(5):
    distances.append([])
    for j in range(5):
        distances[i].append(np.random.randint(5))
print distances
```

So if my list is: [1,2,3,4,5] I want it to be [[1,2],2,3,4,5].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code -

```
In [1]: ls = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [2]: ls[0] = ls[:2]

In [3]: ls
Out[3]: [[1, 2], 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative,

```
newlist = [[a,b],*rest] = ls
```